# AWS service to proxy (NOT REDIRECT) HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, proxy

Is there any aws product that allows to proxy HTTP to HTTPs without having to spin up a EC2 instance and setup nginx or whatever?

Tried API Gateway but seems to only allow HTTPS

Tried putting cloudfront in front of API gateway but all it does is redirect the request.

Not sure if there is any way to do what I need? For legacy reasons (which cannot change so don't bother suggesting that) I need a way to expose an HTTP endpoint and internally proxy it to my host through HTTPS.

I was hoping there's a service I could use to avoid having to manage and maintain another instance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can't Proxy HTTP to HTTPS, that wont work. You must redirect. You mention without having to setup nginx or whatever. Nginx would simply redirect your HTTP request to HTTPS. Same as Cloudfront would do. You can use Cloudfront to redirect HTTP to HTTPS without using API gateway.

Reading your question again, your application only listens on 443? If that is the case use Cloudfront or stick a docker container(nginx) on the EC2 host where your application runs.

Comment: pretty sure you can do that with nginx and proxy_pass, I've done it before. My application listens both 80 and 443, but it redirects all the requests to https/443. However, the request comes from a resource that only supports HTTP, so wouldn't be able to follow the redirect, as doesn't support the encryption etc. So far I've managed to do something with cloudfront and lambda, using nodejs, but I have to manually populate request to an async call and populate the response, is there any app that already does it? or a better solution?

Comment: The problem with what you are doing is that the cert for SSL is tied to a domain name. if you are proxying the headers need to stay the same and not forward to localhost or 127.0.0.1. That's what I was referring to. If Nginx is doing a proxy pass you have to define the upstream proxy, you could in theory do a wildcard SSL and listen at say a.example.com and proxy to b.example.com.